# I am not getting the output while decoding the image url by using b64decode

Tags: python-3.x

My input is image url that can be encoded by using base64.b64encode and again that can be decoded by using b64decode but i am not getting the exact

```
image url

import urllib.request as urllib2
import base64
url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'
contents = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
data = base64.b64encode(contents)
print(data)
de= base64.b64decode(data)
print(de)
```

output:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\\\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\xa6\xe7\xea\xb6\x00\x00\x17\x18IDATx\x01\xed]\x0b\x94\x1cU\x99\xbe:\xd3\x81\xc0.\x82\xc2*\x82\x08\x12\x10\x90\x05\x92\xaa\x9a\x84\x90\xd8]\xb7{\xb2A\xe2A\x81(\xb8\xbb\n\x08\x8a\x1b\\\x84\x98\x05\xe51\x9a\xae\x9a\t\x89\xc0\x02\nA@6\xe1\x81\x06\x17\x10\x1f\x90\xcc$\x01\xf4\x08(\xc8CXX|\x10\x1ed\xfa\x11\x92IUu\x1e\x99dz\xef\xb7\xe6\xb8\xa4\xb7g\xe6\xbf\xd5u\xbb\xaa\x87\xfb\x9dsO\xe71\xd3\xd3g\xea\xd6W\xff\xfd\xff\xef\xff~\x16\x07fv\xad\xdb+\xedTL\xeez\xa7q\xd7\x9fc\xbb\xc1e\xb6\xeb;\xdc\xf1{\xc4\xdf\xe7\x8b\xbf_"\xd6\xb9\xd9\xee`V\xda\xf5\x8fNwUwg\x1a\x1a\x1a\xefL\xa4{6\x1f\xcc\x9d\xcay\xdc\r\xee\xb2]\xff\xcf\xe2\xb5*\xb32yo\xbbx}^|\xef\xcd\xdc\xf5\xff)\xdd\xe5\xed\xcb444\xc6.\xd2\x0b*\x07r7\xf8f&\x1f<\x0b\x12\x88t\xe5\xbd!\xf1\xbe\xabl\'8\xbbs\xd1\xd0\x9eLCCcl\x80\xbb\xdet\xdb\xf1\xef\xcb\xb8\xde\x0e\xdc\xec\xaa\x97 \x92\x01\xee\xfa\x0b\xa7;\xc1\xfe,a\xd0\xd00\x7fxju\xb4\xc5\x18\xd3\xb0\xf3\x1b\xa7\xf2|\xf0\xb0*\xa2 D%\x9bl\xd7_\x80\xfc\n\xd3\xd0\xd0\x04\xd2\x1a\xc8]Y\xf9\xa0 \x8e\x1f\xe1&N\xc4r\xbc~$g\x99\x86\x86&\x90\x04\xa3Z}\x17w\x823q\x84\xc0\x8d\x9b\xb4\x05RKwm\xd8\x9bihh\x02I\x16pL\xe0n\xb0\x0c7j\xa2W\xde\x7f%\xdb\x13Ld\x1a\x1a\x9a@\x92\x81\xdc\xfc\x8d\x87q7x)\t\x04A\xcf\x8dx\xa70\r\rM \x89H\x94\xaeWq\x93g\xdc\xa0h\xbb\xdek\x99|P\xc8\xe4\xbd-Q\x97}\xa1Ca\x1a\x1a\x9a@\xe2A\xc6\xf5\xb3\x19\xd7\xabD\x90\x9b\xf8\xbdx\xbd\x96\xbb\xfe\xe9vOp\xec\xac\xae\xea\x1e\xf5\xf2+\xd3z\x06\xf6\xe1N\xa5\x03\x8aT\xdb\xf5o\x13?\xfb\x8d\xb0?\x13%e\x08\xd0\x98\x86\x86&\x90\xe6#\x9b\xf73\x88\x12\xc2\xde\xc0P\x9f\xdaNp9\x14\xa9\x8d$m\xd3Ne\x8a \xb2\x1b3y?\xd0\xe4\xa1\xa1\t\xa4\x05\xc0]\xff\x98\x8c\x1bl\x0c)\xf2z\xc1\xce\xfbg\x88^\x96v\x16!\x10\x9d\xd8\xae\xff-\xee\x06\xbe&\x0f\rM \tEg\x97\xffw\xc8K\x84 \x0f\x9f;\xfe\xd7@\x1cqiP4yhh\x02\x89\x11\xb3\x97U\xdbl7X-\x1fu\xf8\xbf\xce-\xd8tP\x93\x8fX\x9f\x15D\xe2i\xf2\xd0\xd0\x04\x92\x10p\'\xb8T>Y\x19\\o\xdcTM\xb1\x18\x90\xed\xdexx&\x1f\xfc\xb7&\x0f\rM \t\xc8{\xf0\xbc\xb7M*Q\xea\x04\xdf@\xa2\x93\xc5\x08\xb4\xf9\xc3C\x84ihh\x02\x89\x07]]\xd5ws\xd7\x7fL\x92<\xe61\r\r\rM \x82\x0c>/yl\xb9\x86\x1eyhh\x8cYh\x02\x99y\xed\xd0n\xdc\xf5\xd6H\x94iW!\xd9\xca4444\x81p\'8G\x82<\xd6\xa1\x8c\xca4444\x81 \xf7!\xd3$\'\x92\x95_`\x80\x86\x86\x86&\x10\xf4\xba\xc8h=@8\x0c\xd0\xd0\xd0\xd0\x04\xc2\xf3\xc1\x9dT\x02Ao\x0c\x034444\x81\xa0#\x96\xdai\x9bq\xfd\'t\xd5\xa5u\xa0\xa1\t\xa4\xda\xc5\xde\x8d\xc5T\x01\xe2+j\xf4ASyjT\xd3\xe9\xf6u\xdc\xe8(f\xcdy\xc5\xacuw\x81\x1b\xbf-e\x8dB\xc9\xb6*\x85\xac5\x84W\xfc\x1d\xff.\xfe\xff\xae\xa2m~\xbd\x9c5-|_">\xffj\xd6\xbe\xad\xaf\xbdc[o\xfb\xbcm+\xda\xef\x1e\xecK\xfdv\xeb\x8aTak_\xaa"\xfe\\\x15\x7f\x1e\x14\xab<\xd8\xdb\xf6\x8c\xf8\xba\x1f\x89u\xb1\xf8\xda\xe3\xf1},\x01\xc002\xee\x04\'\xc2h\xdbv\x83^\xb8\xd3\xa1\xa3\xfc\xafs\x86\xf2A\t\x0fCtw\x8b\xaf\xf9\xcc\xd4+\xcb\x7f\xdb\xea\x04\xd2\xdfy\xcc\x9e\xa5\xac5K\xacE%n\xf4\x89\xd75b\x8fm\x16\xaf\xd5\xbf,c\x93\xd8w\x7f*\xd9\xc6\x83En\xe6\xcbY#\x13\xc9~\x83\x04\x9d\xd8\x1a_Iw\x15\xff\x86\r\x0b\x8dR\xd6\x9c(.\xd6wK\xdc*\xe1\xa2I/\xdb,\x8a\xd7\xeb\x8b\x9d\xd6q,\x06l]\x9e:n\xb07u\xbd \x8a"\x88Bv\x89\xef[7\xb8"\xb5X\xbcNb1\x00\x16\x96\xdc\xf5oECg\x08W\xff\x9b\xd3\xdd\x03\x13j\xfa\xacr\x94\xef\x8f\x8b@\xaa\x8c\xbd\xab\xd8i\x9c \x08\xe1N\x10D\xb8\xfdf^\xb9\x8eO9\xa0\x81\xf2\xad\xf7\x0c\xd5\xa8\x98i\xd4E\xd16\xa7\nv\xef\xc5E\x89p\xad(\xe4:\xa6\xb0&\x00\xd1\x83\x88(V\xd0\xc9\x82D&\xab\xb7-o?\x815\x01\xf6|\xffc\xdc\xf1~\xde\xb8\x83\x9d7\x889CS\xae\x1a\x1a\x9ft\x02\xe9\xcfL\x9a\\\xc8\x1a\x8fD\xb2\xd7lk\x8b \x92\x05\x88b\xc2\xe4?v\xd0$\xeb\x95/1\x8d]\xf0f\xda\xd8W\\\x80\xdbq\x11\x14\xae\xa5od\xad\xf7):\xaa\xec+\xc8c)nxUK\xbc\xff]C\xbf`\xfb\xa9\x13?\xfa\xdd8\x96D<\x1e\xe4\x19t\x95\'\x91@\xde\x9ce\xec\x81(W\xc9^\xb3\x8d?K=\xb4\xb2\xdd\x15\x8b\xfaKM\xbb\xde\x11L\xe3\xaf(\xdb\x1d\xbc\xc0\xad\xb5\xf8\xc5\xab^\xe2I\xf3F)g\xa6Y\x84\x10\xf9\x8b\x8c\xc8]\xbc\x89\x9b\\\xf5B\xfed\xb0\xaf\xcdf\x11\x0278w\xbc\'U\x19r\xc3\x0b\x07\x96\x9aI"\x90bz\xe2\x04qTy^\xed^\xb3\xb6\x15\xb9u&\xa3\xc0v\xfd\xcf\x11C\xbb\xcd\xff\xa7\xfd\xd0(q\xeb\x9c\x82ml\xc7/\xbcY\x0b?\xafh\x9bgE\x92\xeb\xe8M\x9d-\x8e\x18\xdbqs7k\xe1\xe7\t\xc2\xfarT\xb9\x0e\x18p\xc7\xe3\xf6\xaf\x80@\xe8\xf9\xb5r\xf3\xf6\x9cq!\x81@\x82Khl\x1c<\xc74\x00V\xe6\xd6\\\xfc\x82c[\xdc\xfcZ\x83\xf9\x8e\x0bqC\xc7\xb5\x04\x89\xccm\xb0\xe5b\x12w\x83\r\xd8\x97\xef\x14\x02\xe9\xef4\x8f.d\xcd\xf5M\xdfk9\xeb\xdc\xd1\x08\xe4*Z\xfe\xc3\xff)S\x8c\xb87\xc14\xd7\xdbo\xf4\xc8\xa3\xe3\x8b\xf8\xc5\xc6\xbd\x8aY+T+\xc1\xd6\x95\xa9\xb3p\x13\xc7\xbd\x10\x01\x85\x1b-2p(w\x832\xae\xd7;\x85@\x8ai\xeb\x03\xe2\x08\xfbz\x1c\xfb\x0cQo\x99w\xd8#\xb4\xef\xfb\xb7\x10#\x90;\xc6:\x81d\xbb7\x1d\xcfF\x00\x92K\xe2B\x0e6\x10\x12\x16\xc4\x8d\xffD\xd1\xb6V\xe3\x15%\xb4F\xce\xa9\xd0\x8dHE\x1e\xab\xda\'\x8b\\\xc4\xb6\x06\x8e k\xc5\xebc\xe2\xe6_\x89W\xf1^\xfd\r\xe4D\xb6m[\xd9>\x95I\xa0s\xd1\xd0\x9e\xdc\r\x9e\x0f{}\xd1\x00\n\xed\x87\xf8\xf3Jx\xde`\x8er\xd2\t\x04\x02\xb0b\xd6\\\x19r\xbfm*p\xeba\xf1\xfd7\x17\xb8y\xad\xd8o\xffQ\xe2\xe6c\xd8;\xb2\xfbv\xed\xcc\xe3\xf6\x1b\xae\x84\xbb\x94( \xbbi\xac\x13\xc8HC\xb9\xd7\xcd\xec\xd8\xabh[\xaf\xca\x1f7\x8c\xa7\xc5\x05\xfc\x97\xf59\xa3\xaeO\xecZ{\xe2\x87\x8b\xdc\x9c#\xce\xb7\xcf\x86\xd8 \xaf\x94\xa7N%\t\xa0D\x15d/!\x08[#}\xb3\xf7\xa6\x9eD\xdeb\xa8o\xfc\x01u\xdfw\xf5\xf8\x03\xc5\xfb~E$H\x9f\x96}o|\x1e|.\xbaW\x8d\xbfX\x9e4\xbcWqL\x87\xe5e=\x055F\x8dp\xd7\x9f\x8b\xd1#I$\x10\xec\x8d\x10\xe4\xf1\xb8\xd8O\x9f}m\xca\x94\xf1\xc3\xede\x1cM *\xa3\xbf\xa7\xb9l\x98\x9b\xd6[B\x9c\xedr\xf3\xd8\'\x90\xca\xb0\t>0\xb8\\\xe8g\xbdV\xe0\x1d\x9f\x82\xd0\x87,\x08\xca\x9a\xa7\xa2\xda"u\x94\xb1\xcd\xabh\x15\x97\xd45\x92y\x8aW\x07\xfb\xc6}\xb2Z\xa5}~|\x9d\xf8\xfaO\x0bRx]\x92H\xae\xa3\x89\x1d\xbd\xb4\xe40\xb1\n&\x03P=z\xf1u \x12LEL\n\x81@"P\xb0\x8d\x8d\xf4\xbd`\xbcU\xb2\x8d3\xa8{\xee\x95tzw\x99rp\xd1\xee\x98Q\'\x02\xf1\xbfO"\x90|p\xf7\x98?\xc2\xe4\xfd\x8b\xea2vn\xf2\x91\x82\x10vH\xd4\xd2\x1f\x1c\x986m\x1f\x16\x02\xd0{@\x90&uF\xb5\xcd\x8f\xb2\x11\xb0e\xc5\xb8#\xc5\xf1c\x87\xc4Q\xe5g\xd5^\xf6\x1e\x16\x02C\x0f\xb1\xf7\x8a#\xcer\x99\xca\xcc\x96\x87\xc6\x1d1\xaa\xd5\xc4N\xb1#q\xfd\x11\x92\x83\xb0\tZTw\x92@ \x90\xa4KD\xa3\xcf#\xca\rYQ\\H\x8cB\x9e\xc5\x91\xaa6,\xbc\x92\x96D\xf5\x1e\x1c\xf3\x11\x88\x13\\<\xcc\x85\\*q!\xef\xad\x1aF\x8a5\x80\xea\xec\xa3\xc6\x15\xb3\xd6O$~\xe6ml\x04\x88hb\x89\xc4\xb1\xe2\x9eF\xfbY\xaaO\xb2\x94x\x9f\xfb$\xa2\x9d\x11\xf3k\x19\xc7;U\x86<\xa6;\xc1\xfe\xac\x01\x80|2n\xf0V\xd3\t\xa4\xf6\x98\x91\xb5|b\x14\xfa_\x88V\x1a\xe9\xdb\xc2Q\x9b\xf2\xb3\x10U\xd7:\xb0\xcf%&Q_\x1e\xeb\x04bw\x07_g5(\xe7&~\x90\xaa\xf7(d\xcd\'\x11\x162\x02hjC\xe3\x19\xa2\xc8l\x10\x99\xfa\xba\x11\xc1\x83l\x7f\xb2\xdecE\xea\t\x91\x93\xd8\x8dE\x80\xa1_\xb3\xf1"/\xf2;j\x142\xb4b\xfc\xb0\xeev\xf0\x9f!\xb6Zx\xc8u\xb0\x08 \xf6\xc2\x8c8\t\xa4\xcc\x8d/\x13\x1f >\xc4e\xe1\x1fV\xb3\xdb\xd0\x80W\xb0\xad\xdf\xd1\xc8\xcaZ\x1d\x92\xdd\xbdA\x9c\x13\xc7v\x0e\xc4\x9f\xc3j\x80.Y\xe2/v\xabx=\x9cE\x88~\xdb\xfa\x18\xc8\xa1\x11m\x084\x17\xc4\x9bx\x8b8\xea\x1c\xc6"\xc4\x96\xbeqGQ\xab>\xe8\xfa\xad\x1f\r\xf8G\xd3\x95\xa3\xc1\xb9,B\xa0)/.\x02)d\xcdG\x89\xd7\xfd\x02\x16\x02\xa8\xaa\x14\xb9u1\x12\xf1\xb2IZ\x1c\x99\xc3]\xa0\x9e\x8a\xc1\x14\x02\xfd\x0c*\x16z}\xc2Z\x15\x08b\xf8\rM\x97a~\x87)\x00:s\x89\x1b\xe91V\x07\x88*\x88G\x89\x85L\x01\x90$\xa5F?\xf5s\x12~\x9eX\xa2}6j\xa54w*\x07\x88\xbd\xb3\xb5\xd9\x04\x82\xfc\x19%\xe7\x86\x84;\x8e\xbb2\x9d\xbb\x90"\xa0w\x0b\x0f\xbc\xd1\xde\x9f\x94\xb8GTA\xcf<\xfbsY\xeb\x01\x1b\xe1\xd3\xc4#\xcc.Y\xe6\r\xe9c\xf7&^\xc8A\x1cu\x98\x02\xa0\xccK\xfa\x0cH\xa6\xd6\x94t\x91\x08\xa5$O\xe1\xed\x81\xa3\x0eS\x80j\xef\xee\x07\x11?\xc3P\xf5\x97l\x9f:\xd5\x97\xa7\x88\t\xf0\x7fd\n`\xe7\x83\xdb\x9bM en~\x92\xf8\xd0\xe8\xa2\xfa\x84\xa0\xf5\x82zL!<,W\xd5\xda\x19\xfe\x8a\xd8\xa1\xb8\xbc\xf5\xc7t\xd2\x9b\x05\xc5\x05:\x91Zua\n\x81\x0bF\xba\xb09\xeb\x1fv}\xfa\xb7\x9dH\xad\xba0\x85\x10\xef\xdfK\xd3\x9c\xb4\xcddo\x03\xbcg\x88\xd1\xa3\x8f\xf6{\x16=\x90\x0b\xf9D\xb3\t\xa4\x98\xb5\xbeMKhN>f\x94\xe8\xf5p\xf1^\xd7\x08\xe2\x18h\x944\x10\xb1\x14m\xe3\x0e\xd8V \x92\xa9\xad\xc4\xb8DQ\xcevL\xecoA\xc3\xe8{\t\xba\x81\x1dp\xb1\n\xd3\xf3".\xd2W\x15\x13\xc8\xbc\x10y\x10\xf4\xbc\\D\xac\x82\xcca\n\x81<\x0c\xf1s\xfc\xdb\xaeO\xff\x8dS\x89\x91\xf1\xfd*\xed>1\xe6\xb5\x89\x04\x82\x1b\xff\x1eJ\xf2\x14%\xd5z\x15\x15TJ\xe0%\x13\x91\x9c}\x8dx0]\xd2\xdfy\xfc\xf0\xf7=w\xbd\xe9\x12\x89\xc6\x0bX\x0b\x01\xeaCJ]\x1f\x83\xb9\xeb<\t\x16S~\xc9\xaaM\x7fJ\xb6\xf5q"\x81\xdcP\x93\xffXL\xbcq;\x14\x13\xc8tb\x1edq\xc8)\x89\xdfd\n\x01\rJ3\t\x046\x97\x84\xd2\xfd3\xbb~\xcf\xe4\xf7\x97\xb8u)\x04\x8c\x11\xb4\xf3\x0f\x89\xf5\x0bTgP\xa5\xa1\xf8G\xb6g\xdc\xa0H\x1c\xe9\xf0\'|=k\x11\xd8=\xc1\xb1\xc4MxW\x1d\x81\xcd\x8f)\xbfpZ\r><`7G\xbc\xf8\xf7\xd4\xdc\xb8?\xa6\xdc\xb8\x10\x7f1\x85@~\x85\xa8A\xb9\xaf\xe6\xe8y1\xedh\xed\xcfV|\x04\xfe\xcf\xe6F \xc6+\x94<\x04\x8e\x12%\xde1\x1d\x9e\xbb\x84\xfe\x16\x92\x92\x15\xa2\xb2\xa2=\xe9\xd00\xbf\xa4\xeb\xc8\xd5\x98\xbc\x7fF\xeb\xcc\xfa\xf5\xbfM\xdc\x84\xe7\xff\x7f\x021\x1f\xa2\xfc\xe2\t,\xdd\x10\xd0\xd3\x10"\x17\x83\xdc\xc3C\x94\x1bW\xa5c7P]\xc6\xc6\x11s1\xbd5^5\x0e1*\xb6\x99B\xa0\x8d\xa3\x99\x04B\xf1\xd3\xfd\xdfH\xc3\xb6\x9e\x8b\xe8\x98\xf2x1\xdb\xf1y\xec3\xe5Oj,4\x1e!_\xd0"\xd3\xf6\xfeH\xd4\xb9\x1c\xc5j\x00gk\x12\x81(\xbe\x01\xa1l%6\xee\xf5\xd5\x10H\x1f\xa5\xfa\xc1\x00\xb5\x04\xd2F\xec\xd0]US\xc2\xed\xa1=\xd0\xbc\x8f+\xce\xa1\xdd\xd8L\x02i\x8ei\x90\xb1\xb9\xc0\xad[\xcb\xf6d#B\x1dF\xf0\xa8\x84\xf0\xea\n\x96pP3\xe8\xb0\xfcG\xae\xa4\xce\x93\xe0~\x92\xb0\x06\xe5S\x85@\x7f\x0c\xb1W\xe1\xbe\x9a#\xcc\xfd\xa4#\xccr\xb6\'S\x08\x94g\x89\x1e!?\xaf\x89\x8a\xbb\x88\xe5\xf7O0\x85@)\xb7\x99\x04\xa2\xd0\xfb\x03\xe5\xfe\x97\xe14\x06\xadI\xac\xf3a \xb0\x81\xad\\\xa2\x93\xa7\xf0~\xa0\x85\xc0\x0b\xeb7\x19\x99K(\x17\x05\x8aQ\xb5\xf6\x89\x93&\xd1{b\xe4{`\xd0l\xa7|T\x04-\x99\xbb\xa4F\t:\xa7\xd1.\xea\x88\x1e\xac\xab\x9aI \xd4\xbe\x14\xea\x82\x8e\x08\x0f\x97\x027:\xd5F\xcb\xb8\xe9\x1c\xef7\x12\xd2\xe1\x97\t\x03yb\x01T\xa5\xe4.\xdc\xf9\xfe\xdf\x0fC W\xd0\xea\xf1\xa6\x9aa[\xf2.h\x97\xd5\x10\xc8\x15\x94\x1bw\xfb\xca\xd4\x19\x8au g\x12\xd5\xb0\xf3C>\xd0\xbe\xa7\xf2\x9e\xc0\x10\xaaf\x12\x08\xa1\x91\x92n`\xc5\xcd\xfc[3\xcc\x0f\xb1f\x01so%Mx\x1e"\xf4\xc84\x15\xe9\x05\x95\x03\xa9\xdd\x94\x10\xd1\r\x7f\xe3\x9a\xa7\x13/\xd6\x0f\x98B`h\x10\xd1\xbf\xf23\xecm\xd8\xde\x97:\x9dV>m\xbbEq\x19\xf7\x0e\xca\xe7\xc0\xe7\xdd\xc5\x81,\xbf\xf9\x10\xe2>|\x89)Bn\xbewd\x93\x85d\xd8w=\r:\xf8?\x02C!\x9a\xcc]\x010@Jr\x86\xc6\xd2\xd9\xcb\xaam,\x01\x80zQ\x90\xdao\xc9G1\xa7r\xf2\xb0\x12\xe0\xf4\xe4\x83\x89]\xb8\xeb\xc3t\xe1Re\xc8\xd4\xb6\xee\xda\'\xcd\xe6\xd5\xbb\x1dL\xac~\xbc%Z\xf8\x95|~\xe4WDr\xd4\xa3|\x8e\xcd\xcbw;\xa4\xf6\xe9O\x95\x17\xa0\x08\xc0\x14\x00\x1a\x93\xa6+Qs\xe6)!\x88\xc3/q\xeb{0_\x8e\xff&\\\x18|@\x90\xc8z\xc9n\xd6e\x18\xf2\xc3b\xc4\xcc\xaeu{q7xD"zzz\xb4\x06,j\xb7b9k~IQ3\xdd\xbf\x127\xd0\x1f\xea;\xb0\xb7\xbdB$\x91s\x14M\xbc\xfb*\xe5\xe7\xe3s\xd6s?\xe3\xf9\xe0Nb\x1e\xebV\x05\xf3u\xdbQql6\x81 i\x0e1\x17Q\xf4\xf5R1k}\x85\x90\xc8o.0pX\xba\x1d>\x1f<\x0c\xf2a1`F~\xd3\x87@\x08\x92\x0ed96\n\xd0K@LT\xbdYL\x1f\x15\xe9\xdc`\xe10\xf5\x1e\x89\x19\xbb\x8b\x1a\xb12\x84\x15\xa1\x88B"\xfd\xfch\xe6\xc3@)\xa2\xf7\xea5\xc3\xa8\xa4O\xa3\xb6Y\xa0\x14\x1fq\x15\xef\xac\x98\xda\xf9\xa1>\xfe%\xe5\xbaC\xec\xc8$As\x81\xb7\x8e\x8f"\x11yS\x88\x91\x80\xfd\xb81\x9b\\\xae\x9dAIt\xd1-\x1a\xe5+ XEnEj<\x8d*\x90\x84_\xe5\xb1\xc3$0\'I\xf8\x93\xde\x10\xf1\xe4\xbb\xdb$\xac\r\'\r7e\x9f\x9c\xcfr\xfc\xc7\xa3\xca\xc7a\xc4\x07\xf6T\x0b\x18\nA@\x18Y\x19\x1b\xbd4p\x81\xdf\xd9\x01\xbe\xa8!q\x19\x8e$d7\xa8:c TG#\xc2}\xea}\xa1H\xce\xf5\xd6\xa6\xbb\xbc}\xa9\x1e\n\xf0\xda \'\xb0\xb8u^D\xe4q\x01\xdd\xf9\xdd\xfa\xd5\xc8f\xc7\xa9\xc7$\xc6-\x9c\x1b\xf5\xd1\x85\xb0\xeaz\x99\xd0\x05e5\xd3\x03\xa0\xe9\x91G\x8d\xc5E\xb0"NG2\x1cI\xa8\x86\xca\x88R\t~\xa84con|\xbf\xf6\x88\x84^\xafF\x99\xf8\x0faH\x04\xce\xd8\x18\\\x05\x8f\xcah\xcf\xa6\x1b\xf6\xb6\x9d\xe0\x1b\xb5y\x1aj\xa8\x8bJ\x93d\x1eb\x96L#\x12\xbasq1\xc2^D\xf1>\x17I\x0e\x99\x9a9J$0K\x82@\x860\xa6\x81\x85\x04\x08Kz\xf2\xdd\xca\xb6\x11\x9f\xa0\xe8\x00\xc7^"?\xbc\x9c\xe0\xbbH\xea\x87\x1f\xd6\x1d,K\x80\xa92\x8e\xcf\xae\xc4\x83\xeb\xc5F<i\xa0v\x16\x91\xc7-\xc3\xe9H\xd0##Y(\xa8)\xa79\xde\xeb\r\xcc[\x19D\xcb5\xec\x13Q%a!0\xbb\xab:\x0eG\x15\xee\xf8?\xa8\xddLR\xcb\xa9\x9c\x17\x8a\x99\t\x9e\x1c5\xebv$\xc3\xa4m\xe6l\xeb\x87r\xd3\xd4\xad\xde\xd1\xc8\n75d\xe2\x92c\x1d\x96@A\x1ab\xd2\xff]\x92\x13\xeaVRFG\x08R\xb8\\\xf2Z\xaf\xb4\xf3\x9b>,7ow\xf3G\xe8\x11\xb7z\x02\x81\xa1U\xc96\xd6I\x94o_Gs\x1d\x93\x04\x9a\xe7\x10\xc5RH*t4\x92\xee\x1e\x98\xc0]oM\x04\xc3\x9b\x06\xa1\xbd\x80\xfa\xd3v\x82\xb3syo\x1a\x8c|`\x1f\x87#\t\xa2\x15{\xfe\xc6\x8f\xc2b\x00\xed\xdc\x08_m7\xe8\xa5\x90\x06\xe1Xu\x19\x0b\x89\xf2\x0c\xe3\x08Y\x1b\xb8\x9d\xb3L/\x1f\xed\xc9\x80n[\xb8K\x89\xe8e\x83$yl\xa1\xfa\xb0bt\x82\xc83l\x95\x9cD\xf7\x96 \x92K\x051\x8cx\x14\x85!2Dk\x82\xa46H\xbe\xffV|.F\x00r!<\x1f\xbc(\x97\xd4\xf76q\xc7[\x84\x07\xe0h\txL\'\xc0\xd7\'o\xb0\x94u\xa6lI\x17\xba!\xe4\xee\xf0`\x19mO\x8b}w\x9d\xcc\xbeF4"\x88\xea\xe4\xd0\x02-\x0c\xd9N\xd2L\xd2f\xf6\xee\x14\xb9q~X\x7f\x85\x9d\xde\xaa\xd7\xc3\xa4\x08y\x12\xbcb\xa8\x0f\xbc\x1fjJv\xe4\x85D\x9b\xa4\xa0\xeb\xfc\x90#-w\x88*\xc9\xe3\xf07\x85I\x11&\xd5\xe1U\xfc\xdb\xf5\xf02\xc5\xb1\'\xcc\xfb"O\xc2$\x00O\xdeZ\x8fR\x99\x92=w\x82\x1b\xe0\xbc\x0f\xe9\xbb\xed\xfa\x17r7\xb8\x16\xed\x0e\x828\x86\x92:\xda\x12$P\xd3\x93E^;\'\xcf-\x85B\x19\xa5^\xec;\x98\x03\xe1\xa8R\xcc\x1a/\x84|\xcf\xe701\x80\x85\x05\xa4\xeb\xdc\xf1\x7f\xd2*\xc4\x81\xcda\xbb>m\xa3\x12\x8e2\xb0uK\xc2pm\xcc9\xc5\xe7\x91\xcdO\x90T\xa1\xea\x17\xc8c)>O\x08a\xd7\x17q]\xdfI\xc3\xb5\xd1\xf8\x86&\xb8\xb8\xf7\x1c\x92\xb5\xfd\x9d\x1d\x87D\xd2&o;\xc1<\x82\xd5[\xac+\xe3\x06\x1b3Np\x12\x8b\x10\x90\x07\x13|B\x94\xae\x027\x7f\x86\xa4WXo\x0e\xf8\x84\xc4<\x99\x7f9\xe6\xcf(\xf0xia\x02!\xe4)\xb2F\x7f\\{\x0e\x15\xa1r\xce2\xa3vj\x9aD\xb0{\x8be\xa1)\xd0\xce\x0f\x1c\xca\x14\x00!\x1c!\xacT\xb4\x8c{\x1b\xa9\xcd\x03\xd5\x07\xd8\x1eh\xf5\x8f)\xf2x\x00C\xa7\x1anps\xfd\xf9\xef$\x02\x010\x8f\x05\x89\xd28"\x0f\xbaoH\x88\x9a9f\xcaf\xf2\xc1@B\x8e,\x9b`\x85\xa7\xdav\x11.dEn]\xdd\xe4\x0b\xb9\x10?7B\x93\x9f\xab\x9bJ \xbd\xa9\xef\x10\xc6f\x92\x81AR*\xa3`\xe4[P\x12\x8e\x9d@j\x12\xee\xc8\xa75q\xcf\xfd\xbe\x905?\xc2T\x03\xc2,TVp\x03\xc7s\\\x81\xfd\xbf\xb7\x04\x19u\xd6D\x94\xb2\x1d\')\x0e-Q>[\x8b\x11\x13L\x01D\'\xeeI"\t\xda\xaf\x928\xf0\xfe\x98\xf4\xafFLX\xb1`+\xa1`?U`T\x04Uu\x92\x08\x04xy\xe6\x84\xdd\xf00AED-y\x987\x10\x12\xa6\xd1\x13\t\xca\xa5\xb6\xeb\xbd\xd6\xac\x88\x03\xeaC\x94~Y\x93Q3\x08y\x11\xca\xaaQ\xdb\xce\x95\xb2\xe6\x95\xaa\x1b\xa5D>b/\x11\x1d,\xc2x\xcbH\x89\x03\xef\x87\xa8\x03\x93\xfe\x15\x023al\xd7\xffVT\x0f\xaf\xbfT\x1a\xfdc\x98\x00\x85@\x90\xa8WB \x846\x8b\x02\xb7\x1e\x8e\x9a8\x10\xe1\x14s\xc64\x16\'\xa0\x04\x84\xf0\xcbv\xfc[\xb8\x1b\x94#&\x8dm\xf0!\xe1NpNn\xc1z\x85\x9bS\xbe\t\xa9\xc4\xadnD$\x8dF\x1c\xc5\xac\xe9\xd4\xcc\xe2P\x0e\xe8=\xc4\x8d\xdf\xddhD\xb2\xb3\x81\xae\x07\xfa\x90fw\x91C\xcfQ\xd3;C^\x18\xff\x81\xb1%\x10-\xbe\xad\x1f\xac\x93r\xd4QF \x84\xca`9kd\x90\x93\x1be\x08<\xc9S\x17\xaak\xbcg\xe2\xcc\x8d\x11j"Wb;\xc1=0\x80\x81\xa4\\\xa2\x86\xbf\xc6v\xbc\x079\x12gNp"A\xcd\x1a+\x90\xa7\x10\xe7\xc6\x1cr$\x85\xac\xf5\xd4h\x03\xb2\xf1\xff\x98\xec\x8f\x99\xa3\x85\x9c\x95U\xed\xf2N\xca\x8f\xf4\xb6\xe5\x90#\x11G\x9c\xa70\xfar\xb4\xe9\xfab\n\xde\xd3"\xda\xf8w\xf1\xdaY}\x92\xa5\x98"\x90Egn\xe5SP-\xc3\xefv\x14\xd2X\x07\xff\x1b\x8c\x86\x00q\x84\xb1\xf9\xc4{\xb0\x04\x00\x0f\x1c\x8c\xb0\x14Q\xeb2b\xb2\xb5\x8c\x8a\x1e\x06\x92\xd1{i\x12\x02$_\xa1\x10L;\x95)8k\xda\xaew\n,\x040\xc7V\\\xb4\x99\x99\xee\xcadH\x8bc\xf0\x18Q\xe2\xaa^LO\x9cP\xb6;8T|%\xdb8\x03\xaf\xf8;\xfe\x1d\x1d\x90,\xc1\x00!\x08s\xa2\t\xa2g\x85\x0f\xf6\x8e;y\xfb\x8a\xd4\xe7\xb6\xaf\x1c7\x1b$\x03%)J\xc3,\xc1\x98\xd63\xb0\x0f\x1e` \x03\xec1\xec\xb5\x8c\xeb\xa5s\x0b6\x1d4J\xe3\x1d\x08\xe4\x0b\xf4\xa1d\xc9\x02\xa4\xf0\x82L&\xa2W\xaa\xc8\x8d\xd3\xe0X\x87\x08\xa3?3i2\xa2e\xc5\x91\x86\x86\x86\x06\x14\xcc\x04\x02Y\xc5j\xa1\xa1\xa1\xa1\x81#\xf7h\x04\x82<\x1fk=hhh \xbf\x06A\xa3\xaa\xf7\x86\'\xeb\x18\x9b\x17\xad\xa1\xa11\xa3k\xe0\xbd\xdc\xf5\xe7b\xf2 \xca\xa8*\xca\xf8\xe8\x08\'jFN`\x1a\x1a\x1a\xc9\x07:r9\xaa+\xae\xb7y\xd7\x9b\xd8\x7f\x00\t\xd1fO\'\x80\xf6$\xc1\x89~\r\r\r\x94e\xe1\r3\xda\xa4A|Md?\xd3\xa9\x98\x88l\x08\xf9\x8f\x9f2\r\r\x8d\xe4\x02\xbe\x1dD\xbd\xd0f\xc8\x02X\x83\x80eE&\x1f\xbc@\x9c\xcb\xfb\xcfLCC#\xb9\xc8\xcd\xdfx\x18Ux\x88\xa6\xceF\xa6\xf5C\xa4\x08\x07<\xa2\xc8q\xc3\xac\xae\xea\x1eLCC#\xd9\xc8\xb8\xfe\x8dR\xad\x0e!:\xb21\xddN\xc6q\xcfv|\x97\xb5\x0644t\xd5\x05%U\xc9Ag/b8\x14\xa2\x8a\x91z\xb6\xe0\xcb\x8b1$\xe8\xe8\x96\xe8\x9b\x19\xc0gb\xad\x01\r\r\rH\xd1\xc3\xfaz\x88\x1b\xfeQ\xdb\xf1\x17\xdb\xae\xef r@D\xc3\x1doy\xb8\xc6;,\x7f\x0ek-hhh\x80\x00\xe26\xadB\x8e\x04"3\xd6\x8a\xd0\xd0\xd0\xcaSoi\\\xe4\x81\xee^\x0c\xbab\x1a\x1a\x1aI\x05aj~>\xb8\xbd\xe9\xe4\x81\xb9\xcf\xdd\x1b\x0fg\xad\x0f\r\r\x1d\x89 \x97\xd1D\x02y\x89`\xd2\xddJ\xd0\xd0\xd0\xc0\xd8\x0e8\x89\xa9=\xb6\x04w*s\xbe\xd3\xd0\xd0\x88\xdf0\x88;\xc1uQ;\xb4C\x8d\n\xb3+6\xf6\xa1\xa1\xa1\x01\x871\xee\x04W\xa34\xdb\xc8$C\x9e\x0f\xfa\xe0ZF\x98\xf0?\xd6\xa0\xa1\xa1\x01oS\xd8b\n"\xb9\x86;\xfe\xe3#\rf\xcf\xe4\xbd-P\x9f\xda\xae\x7f\x1bDg0ff\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1ao\x9fd\x87\xd2k\xda\xf5\x8f\xe6N\xa5\x03\xfe\xa8\xdc\xf5\x8e\xe2\xae\xff~\xad\xe7h5hhhhhhhh\xfc\x0f\xd4\x88i\xf0\x19\xbd\xf1\xa6\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

Comment: what did you expect? that all looks as it should as far as i can tell...

Comment: The same image url would be the output

Comment: you did not encode the url; you downloaded content from the url (a PNG image) and encoded that.

Comment: Then how would i get the image url as out can you tell me

Comment: `url_enc = base64.b64encode(url.encode())` and decode with `base64.b64decode(url_enc).decode()`.